# Difference between 'character set' and 'default character set'

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, alter-table

Is there any difference between statements

`ALTER TABLE xxx DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8`

and

`ALTER TABLE xxx CHARACTER SET utf8` ?

MySQL documentation keeps silence about functionality of `DEFAULT` keyword.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference. `DEFAULT` is an optional keyword.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-table.html.

Optional keywords that don't do anything are quite common in SQL, for example `INSERT INTO` is the same as just `INSERT`. It’s a question of style whether you include optional keywords. They don't have any effect on the function of the query, but they might make it more readable.